# "Warning: Error in read.xlsx.default: File does not exist." works fine on my local machine, fails when deployed

Tags: rstudio

works fine on my local machine but when i publish it on Rconnect it throws this warning and exits.
I don't have this function "read.xlsx.default" in my .Rmd file. This code is working on my machine and not when i deploy it on Rconnect server.
also i get this log:
"The following objects are masked from 'package:shiny':dataTableOutput, renderDataTable"
example:

```
T1_list<-read.xlsx('data/Folder1/static/T1_data.xlsx', 
                        sheet = 'Sheet1', 
                        cols = 1:2)
```